# Is exists Linux app for stdin/stdout via a ring buffer with the output of the last data to the dump file if there is a problem when reading/writing

Tags: linux, console

I need to find a block with erroneous data. The data stream arrives at the stdin and is processed by the utility with an error. For testing, I need to identify which data leads to the error. All that came to dump is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what I didn’t find. Wrote a short utility. I hope someone will be interested.

https://github.com/sergey-sh/dumpedlastbuf